# How to use wsdl in ASIFormDataRequest in iphone

Tags: iphone, soap, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

I have tried to request wsdl service using ASIFormDataRequest, But it is not reply properly. Can you please anyone guide what is my fault.

```
#define SIGNON @"http://smile.stanford.edu:8080/SMILE/spring-ws/StudentSignOn.wsdl"



    NSString *Message  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                          "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                          "<soap:Body>\n"
                          "<stdSignon xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                          "<username>%@</username>\n"
                          "<password>%@</password>\n"
                          "</stdSignon>\n"
                          "</soap:Body>\n"
                          "</soap:Envelope>\n",txtUserName.text,txtPassword.text];


    NSMutableData *soapdata = [[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[Message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] autorelease];

    ASIFormDataRequest *_ASIFormDataRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:SIGNON]];
    [_ASIFormDataRequest addRequestHeader:@"Namespace" value:@"http://stanford.edu/smile/studentsignon/schema"];    
    [_ASIFormDataRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8"];
    [_ASIFormDataRequest addRequestHeader:@"EndpointURI" value:@"http://stanford.edu/smile/studentsignon"];
    [_ASIFormDataRequest setTimeOutSeconds:20];
    [_ASIFormDataRequest setPostBody:soapdata];



#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_4_0
    [_ASIFormDataRequest setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
#endif
    [_ASIFormDataRequest setDelegate:self];
    [_ASIFormDataRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(asyncFail:)];
    [_ASIFormDataRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(asyncSuccess:)];
    [_ASIFormDataRequest startAsynchronous];
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `ASIFormDataRequest` and I think it's the best networking framework. And it's easy to use too. Try to delete custom selectors and put `NSLog` in `-asyncSuccess:` method.

```
- (void)asyncSuccess:(ASIFormDataRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"finished");
    // your code from asyncSuccess:
}
```

If `NSLog` is called, you can get server output via `[request responseString]` or `[request responseData]`.

Comment: I received requst from [request responseString].

Comment: But what's your issue? Is it `NULL`? What is the problem?

Comment: HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
X-Cache: MISS from local.sdi.local
Server: Apache
Expires: Wed, 27 Jul 2011 09:49:19 GMT
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from local.sdi.local:3128
Via: 1.0 local.sdi.local (squid/3.0.STABLE13)
Proxy-Connection: close
Vary: accept-language,accept-charset
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Wed, 27 Jul 2011 09:49:19 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes